# After video plays show another video in its place (Vimeo)

Tags: javascript, video, vimeo

I am looking to have a video play once the first video ends. Both videos are coming from Vimeo. I have attempted to use [this plugin](https://github.com/jrue/Vimeo-jQuery-API) and follow the Vimeo API however I can't seem to get anywhere. The plugin successfully plays one video after the other but the video loads next to it, not in place of it. I've also tried the suggestion on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25695602/3393535) but it doesn't work for me either.

Any suggestions? I'm beginner level for Javascript so the more detail the better :) thank you!

Comment: You simply have to change the `src` of the iframe to your new video url on finish, something like `frogaloopVar.addEvent('finish', function(){ iframeVar.src = 'new_video_url?api=1&player_id=' + iframeVar.id; })` Then trigger a play on it again.

Comment: @somethinghere I tried to implement the code but it does not seem to be working. Any suggestions?

`<iframe id="first" src="//player.vimeo.com/video/138237168?&api=1&player_id=first" width="500" height="281" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>
 
 <script>
  
  frogaloopVar.addEvent('finish', function(){ iframeVar.src = '//player.vimeo.com/video/138237168?api=1&player_id=second' + iframeVar.id; })
  
 </script>`